# How to control Notification group clicks

Tags: android, android-notifications

This question is about Android [Grouped Notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group).

According to the official documentation, it mentions:

> Note: If your app sends four or more notifications and does not specify a group, the system automatically groups them together on Android 7.0 and higher.

The problem is I found that this group of notification is clickable.

In my testing, I received a total of 5 notifications, 4 of them have their own pendingIntents, one of them is just a foreground service notification which is un-clickable and not dimiss-able.

While their clicking behavior worked correctly when separated, when I click on a group of them, Android simply creates on top of my current activity stack, another entrance Activity.

I know that I can force separate them into different notifications without grouping them, by specifying a different group ID for each of them;

Is there a way to preserve the notification group feature, but making the group non-clickable?

Comment: Hi Sira, have you solved your issue? I am facing same issue, while clicking on group I am not able to get intent data so I want to make it non clickable. Please help me if you can.

Comment: @Pankaj If I recall correctly I finally decided to separate them into different groups....

Comment: if you don't mind, can you please explain how I can force then to become separate  notification.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when a user clicks a group of notifications, you must open the screen where these "notifications" will be seen. For example, you are developing a social network app. You receive 3 notifications about new messages. You can group all of them as a "New message" and when a user clicks this type of group notification you must open the screen of the chat list. And if you receive 2 notifications about new friend requests, you can group them as a "Friend request" and when a user clicks to this group you must open a friend request list where all requests are shown.